# The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, associations

**"The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations."**

I am getting this error in Entity Framework 4.4 when updating/migrating the database, but I am not trying to specify a 1:1 relationship.  I want something like this:

```
public class EntityA
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int EntityBID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EntityBID")]
    public virtual EntityB EntityB { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PreferredEntityAID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PreferredEntityAID")]
    public virtual EntityA PreferredEntityA { get; set; }
}
```

where EntityA must have an EntityB parent, whereas EntityB can have a preferred EntityA child, but doesn't have to.  The preferred child should be one of the children associated with the parent, but I don't know how to enforce this in the database.  I'm planning on enforcing it programmatically.

How do I get around this error or what is a better way of accomplishing these relationships?

Comment: `[ForeignKey("EntityAID")]` means, that there should be `EntityB.EntityAID` property. Have you missed it in a sample?

Comment: Do you mean [ForeignKey("PreferredEntityAID")]?

Comment: Thanks for catching that. Just missed it in my example. I edited it.

Comment: I came across this issue too, but it was simply because when I populate EntityB, I forgot to populate EntityA into B's navigation property

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Entity Framework Code-First conventions are assuming that `EntityA.EntityB` and `EntityB.PreferredEntityA` belong to the same relationship and are the inverse navigation properties of each other. Because both navigation properties are references (not collections) EF infers a one-to-one relationship.

Since you actually want two one-to-many relationships you must override the conventions. With your model it's only possible with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityA>()
    .HasRequired(a => a.EntityB)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(a => a.EntityBID);

modelBuilder.Entity<EntityB>()
    .HasOptional(b => b.PreferredEntityA)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(b => b.PreferredEntityAID);
```

(If you use this you can remove the `[ForeignKey]` attributes.)

You cannot specify a mapping that would ensure that the preferred child is always one of the associated childs.

If you don't want to use Fluent API but only data annotations you can add a collection property in `EntityB` and relate it to `EntityA.EntityB` using the `[InverseProperty]` attribute:

```
public class EntityB
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PreferredEntityAID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PreferredEntityAID")]
    public virtual EntityA PreferredEntityA { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("EntityB")] // <- Navigation property name in EntityA
    public virtual ICollection<EntityA> EntityAs { get; set; }
}
```