# Creating entity relation with AspNetUsers in EF Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, guid

I use `ASP.NET Identity` in an `MVC` project and I need to create entity relation between `ASP.NET Identity AspNetUsers` entity and my custom tables. As it is known, `AspNetUsers` table uses **string** for **Id** field and there is **GUID** values in this **Id** field. However, I am not sure about the issues below:

**1)** What data type should I use in my custom classes in order to create `PK/FK` relation? **string** or **GUID**?

**2)** How can I make this custom **Id** field to be generated automatically for every new record? Is it also possible to make it `sequential` so that the records can be sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-You should use `string`. (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884399/aspnetusers-id-as-foreign-key-in-seperate-table-one-to-one-relationship))

If you open the `edmx` you see that `Id`(GUID) in `AspNetUser` is `string`.

2-You can use constructor in model and generate GUID filed in it like this:

```
public partial class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        Id = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
    //Other fileds
}
```

3- for **Sequential Guid Generator** see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752004/sequential-guid-generator).I suggest `UuidCreateSequential`.

Comment: Selam Ali, Thanks for reply. In that case:
**1)** Ok, I use string and keep GUID values in it. But I am not sure if I have to use anything special in this Entity. Is your example is suitable for it?

**2)** Could you please give an example implementation? 

**3)** There are several answer on that page. Which one do you suggest?