# AspNetUsers one-to-one relationship to another table with more user (Employee) info

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I am using ASP NET MVC with Individual User Accounts as Authentication for my project. In my database, I have an `Employees` table which stores info about employees: `Id, First Name, Last Name, Address` and so on.

Before registering any account, I want to know how to link users created in the `AspNetUsers` table to the ones I have in the `Employees` table.

I want to do it via a `ForeignKey` which will have the `Id` from the `AspNetUsers` table as a FK in the `Employees` table. The relationship between the two tables must be one-to-one.

I have tried both solutions from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884399/aspnetusers-id-as-foreign-key-in-separate-table-one-to-one-relationship) on SO but both results in errors. I am using Code-First migration.

Comment: Let us see your code and tell us the error message.

Comment: @DavidStania I was able to solve the issue. Keys in ASP NET are stored as string and I was using **int** type in my `Employee` class for the `ForeignKey`.