# Can't set the Relation between 2 DB Models

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, ef-code-first-mapping

I Got This Issue:

I Have the Application User Class Like This

```
 
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ROLES Role { get; set; }
        public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
        public int? AreaId { get; set; }
        public string Document { get; set; }
        public bool Enable { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AreaId")]
        public virtual Area Area { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection Measures { get; set; }

    }
```

And I Got this another Model:

```
 

public class Area
    {
        public int AreaId { get; set; }
        public string AreaName { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
        [Key, ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
```

And when i try to:
**add-migration**

the PM Console throws:

***Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'x.Models.ApplicationUser' and 'x.Models.Area'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.***

I have been trying all day but I can't find a way to tell the Entity Framework to recognize the relation.

Any ideas?

Thanks for reading

Comment: I think it's choking on you Company navigation properties. It looks like it's required in the Area class. Try using the Required attribute there or use fluent API to specify that one is required and the other optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254724/the-principal-end-of-this-association-must-be-explicitly-configured-using-either)

This Post give me the Answer I Need!!!
It's pretty hard to find...

So I let you the post here...
Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add Attribute for AreaId in Area class

```
[Key]
public int AreaId { get; set; }
```

and if you want 1-1 relationship for ApplicationUser and Area update your code like

```
[Unique]
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

Comment: I want to AreaId in ApplicationUser its a Optional Key
And also Application user its a OptionalKey in Area.

Comment: No...
I want a 1-1 Optional relationship.
The ApplicationUser on Area Its Optional and can be just 1 per Area.
And the Area on ApplicationUser can be just 2 per User.

Comment: Can you give me an example with data

Comment: Okey i Want something like this:
ApplicationUser...

Id= hf9d8fm-as9d (Or something like that...)
CompanyId = 9997654(But this can be null too) (ForeignKey)
AreaId = 665 (This can be null too) (ForeignKey)
Document = 10098264926
Enable = true

In the other side AreaId can be:

AreaId = 7789 (PrimaryKey)
AreaName = IT Deparment
CompanyId = 88998752 (This Can't be null an Area Always be part of a Company)
UserId = ajd9d7kas-djdj0as8sydh (This is the boss of the area, and can be null too)

Comment: In that order...


ApplicationUsers store me all the users of different Companies
And Areas Store me all the areas of different companies...

An User can have an Area or Not
So Can Have a Company or Not.

And an Area can have a Boss Area or Not
But always have a Company.