# Entity Framework foreign key references not mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using EF6 and .NET 4.6.1. I know this somewhat is a duplicate (I've looked at [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254724/the-principal-end-of-this-association-must-be-explicitly-configured-using-either)) but hear me out. My case is different and I have tried to get it to work using their solutions with mine but it didn't work. So no this isn't actually a duplicate. It's another issue altogether and I haven't found a post that really helps me on this topic.

I am trying to map relationships between 3 models; `Employee`, `Position` and `Employment`. I want a one-to-many between `Employment` and `Position` (employments map to one position) and a one-to-one between `Employment` and `Employee`.

```
public class Employment
{
    public int EmploymentID { get; set;}
    ...
    public Position Position { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}

public class Position
{
    public int PositionID { get; set;}
    ...
    [InverseProperty("Position")]
    public ICollection<Employment> Employments { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set;}
    ...
    [InverseProperty("Employee")]
    public Employment Employment { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I try to run this with `DbContext` automapping, it fails and says it can't find the relationships. I've tried multiple combinations of data annotations like setting inverseproperties and foreignkey("____ID") on some of them but haven't been able to get it to work.

I did also try adding virtual keywords in for some of the but that didn't do anything either.

I'd rather not use FluentAPI as I want to let the auto mapper do as much as possible with this. It's not complicated a problem enough to warrant manually mapping it with FluentAPI (At least in my opinion it isn't. Maybe I'm wrong).

What data annotations do I need? I've looked at [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254724/the-principal-end-of-this-association-must-be-explicitly-configured-using-either) and various articles on [entityframeworktutorial.net](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) trying to apply their solutions to my case. But haven't gotten anything to work.

The failing line is here:

```
using (EmploymentContext ctx = new EmploymentContext())
{
    Position pos = new Position()
    {
        PositionID=1,
        Name="General Manager"
    };
    ctx.Positions.Add(pos); // Failing here
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

and the error message is:

> 'Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types `'Ianmann.Hr.DataAccess.Employment.Employee` and `Ianmann.Hr.DataAccess.Employment.Employment`. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.'

Comment: Can you please add the PK properties to the sample models.

Comment: Doesn't it work if you remove those `InverseProperty` completely?

Comment: @IvanStoev there you go, I just added them.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That's what I tried at first. no it doesn't work

Comment: Ok, so what exactly says the error message? There are multiple relationships there and you didn't post what exactly fails

Comment: Just added it to the end of my question. there's the failing line and message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you insist on using data annotations. Everything you can do with data annotation can be done with the Fluent API, but the opposite is not true. Also, and especially with relationships, the data annotations are not intuitive and error prone.

In the concrete case the problem is with the one-to-one relationship (btw, the error message should contain that information). It's because EF cannot determine the principal and the dependent of the relationship when the ends of the relationship are both optional (as in your case) or both required. So one way to resolve it is to mark the principal by making the navigation property required:

```
public class Employment
{
    public int EmploymentID { get; set; }
    ...
    public Position Position { get; set; }

    [Required] // <--
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

The `InverseProperty` is redundant (not needed) in this case.

The same can be achieved more intuitively with fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employment>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.Employee)
    .WithOptional(e => e.Employment);
```

But please note that while either way will resolve the issue in question, the resulting design will be the so called [Shared Primary Key association](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations), where `EmploymentID` is both PK and also FK to `Employee`. In case you want a separate FK property / column, then fluent API is a must as it cannot be done via data annotations:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employment>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.Employee)
    .WithOptional(e => e.Employment)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("EmployeeID"));
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to EntityFramework and am used to Djangos ORM in which all of that mapping was automatically done by the ORM implicitly. So I'll have to look into Fluent API more then.

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped :) And yes, looking at fluent API is a good idea, especially if you are going to use EF Core (which is the "future of EF" according to MS) at some point, where data annotations are almost retired - I mean, they exists, but have even more limitations than in EF6.