# Entity framework WithRequired fluent api to data annotations mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to do Data Annotation approach in my code first entity framework project.

Here are my entities: (showing limited fields)

```
public partial class CUSTOMEREXT
{
    [StringLength(36)]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public virtual CUSTOMER CUSTOMER { get; set; }
}

public partial class CUSTOMER
{
    [StringLength(36)]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public virtual CUSTOMEREXT CUSTOMEREXT { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API: (This works)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<CUSTOMER>()
        .Property(e => e.ID)
        .IsFixedLength()
        .IsUnicode(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<CUSTOMER>()
        .HasOptional(e => e.CUSTOMEREXT)
        .WithRequired(e => e.CUSTOMER);

    modelBuilder.Entity<CUSTOMEREXT>()
        .Property(e => e.ID)
        .IsFixedLength()
        .IsUnicode(false);      
}
```

Dynamically generate model builder: **(This does not work)**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType())); //Current Assembly
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Code to test:

```
Model1 model = new Model1();
var outp = model.Set<CUSTOMEREXT>().ToList();
var out1p = model.Set<CUSTOMER>().ToList();
```

Error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'OraclePOC.CUSTOMER' and 'OraclePOC.CUSTOMEREXT'. The principal
>   end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the
>   relationship fluent API or data annotations.

By looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17254724/1169180), I know I have to convert `WithRequired` to data annotation attribute. Not sure How?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out:

Add `[Required]` attribute:

```
public partial class CUSTOMEREXT
{
    [StringLength(36)]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual CUSTOMER CUSTOMER { get; set; }
}
```