# after error by enable migration in asp.net mvc not core

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'ClassLibraries.Entities.Product' and 'ClassLibraries.Entities.Category'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

this is the error

successfully enabled migrations

Comment: Is this your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254724/the-principal-end-of-this-association-must-be-explicitly-configured-using-either

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.